# Write ${2-i} \over {-1-5i}$ in factored form?

Tags: factoring

Trying to help someone study for a final exam. My background: Calculus 1, Statistics.

I haven't done this kind of math in ages. Considering $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$, I was thinking rationalize the denominator?

Comment: I guess that "factored form" is something of the form $k(a+bi)(c+di)$, and if so, try multiplying both numerator and denominator by $-1+5i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: multiply the numerator and denominator by $-1+5i$.

$${{2-i} \over {-1-5i}} \cdot \frac{-1+5i}{-1+5i} = \frac{(2-i)(-1+5i)}{1+25}$$

Now expand the numerator and simplify.

Comment: Thank you, glad to know I was on the right track!